# How to remove comma, form python program

Tags: python, counter

I would like to remove the comma my counter application makes at the end of each line. I've tried the r.strip thing, but I'm not sure how to use it properly.

REPL LINK: [repl](https://repl.it/repls/SuperficialSparklingQuotient)

```
def counter(start, stop):
  x = start
  if start > stop:
      return_string = "Counting down: "
      while x >= stop:
          return_string += str(x)
          x = x-1
          if start != stop:
              return_string += ","
  else:
      return_string = "Counting up: "
      while x <= stop:
          return_string += str(x)
          x = x + 1
          if start != stop:
              return_string += ","

  return return_string

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? What is the actual output you're seeing and how does that compare to your "Should be [...]" comparison

Comment: Not exactly, It's an online course about python, and I need help here, I've made the rest of the function already.

Comment: You might consider collecting the digits in a list and then using `', '.join(that_list)`

Comment: You can try adding `If len(return_string) > 1: return_string = return_string[:-1]` before the return.

Comment: Why are you comparing start and end  in the condition? those are constants

Comment: I'm not really doing that, they were pre-made by my course. I had to just complete the function to count down and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like a correction to your code, you can change your condition a bit to adjust how the comma is added (though there are many fancy ways you could write better):

```
def counter(start, stop):
  x = start
  if start > stop:
      return_string = "Counting down: "
      while x >= stop:
          return_string += str(x)
          x = x-1
          if x != stop-1:
              return_string += ","
  else:
      return_string = "Counting up: "
      while x <= stop:
          return_string += str(x)
          x = x + 1
          if x != stop+1:
              return_string += ","

  return return_string
```

Or in a quick way, you can replace this line of your code:

```
return return_string
```

with:

```
return return_string.rstrip(',')
```